# How to find the probability of error of this jury

Tags: probability

The question is:
Suppose that:

(1) The probability of guilt of an accused is 1/2.

(2) The a priori reliability of every juror is: the probability that the juror votes guilty if a person is innocent is p1 < 1/2. The probability that a juror votes innocent a person if they are guilty is p2 < 1/2.

(3) Suppose each juror acts independently.

Find the probability of error of this jury (i.e., that they convict an innocent person or acquit a guilty person) if the jury split is:

$(1) ~12:0 \\
(2) ~9:3 \\
(3) ~8:4 \\
(4) ~7:5 \\
(5) ~5:3 \\
(6) ~9:0 \\
(7) ~112:100 \\
(8) ~501:500$

The interpret a split of the jury, say, 9:3, as: at least 9 of the jurors have to agree on a vote of guilty or innocent. This means that 9 juries vote guilty (resp. innocent) and 3 juries vote innocent (resp. guilty), or 10 juries vote guilty (resp. innocent) and 2 juries vote innocent (resp. guilty), or 11 juries vote guilty (resp. innocent) and 1 jury votes innocent (resp. guilty), or 12 juries vote guilty (resp. innocent) and 0 juries vote innocent (resp. guilty).

My idea is that for example, 2) 9:3
P(error)=P(9 or more guilty votes | accused is innocent)+P(3 or less innocent votes | accused is guilty)=p1^9+p2^3+p1^10+p2^2+p1^11+p2^1+p1^12
Can someone point out if there is something wrong with my idea? Thank you!

Comment: Please use MathJax to format your post.  It's much easier to read that way.  Here is a primer:  https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: Appreciated, I will be aware of this next time!

Comment: Please edit your question (using the edit link above) to do it this time.  Thanks.